# Zoom Controller doesnt work Mapbox and Angular js

Tags: angularjs, zooming, leaflet

Im trying to work with Angular.js and Mapbox.

The map is loaded, from Mapbox with no problem. But the Zoom Control have problems, in the browser it shows the Zoom Control, but it doesnt appear in the Android Emulator. In the browser and in the emualtor, they dont work: they cant zoom in or zoom out.

I draw another Zoom Control and it happen the same problem, both in the browser appear and both doesnt Zoom in or Zoom out. In the browser they show both zoom control and Android Emulator both Zoom Controller doesnt appear and they doesnt work.

I have try this work Mapbox with no problem outside Angular:

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/

Could some one could explain me or give me a hand.
thanks in advance

Here is the code that I was working:

> .controller('loa', function($scope, $ionicModal) {
>
> // MAPAS ------------------------------------------------------------>
>   $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/calama.html', {
>       scope: $scope   }).then(function(modal) {
>       $scope.modal1 = modal;
>         }, {
>       animation: 'slide-in-down',
>       focusFirstInput: true,
>       scope: $scope   });
>
> $scope.cierra1 = function() {
>       $scope.modal1.hide();   };
>
> $scope.mapaCalama = function() {
>       $scope.modal1.show();
>       L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.xxxxxx';
>       var map = L.mapbox.map('map')
>         .setView([-22.4562, -68.9249], 6)
>
> ```
>   .addLayer(L.mapbox.tileLayer('itelius.xxxxx'));
>
>
>     L.mapbox.featureLayer('itelius.xxxxxx').on('ready', function(e) {
>   var clusterGroup = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();
>
>   e.target.eachLayer(function(layer) { clusterGroup.addLayer(layer); });
>   map.addLayer(clusterGroup);
>           });         };
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I recentley put a zoom-slider object and works, but when I add a zoom control and try it I cant zoom in or zoom out.

Comment: It could be also the css from leafflet that are in conflict with the zoom